# Entity Framework 6 and SQL 2012+ Identity Column PK -vs- Sequence PK fix?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Is there any sort of sane fix or work around for situations where we have to use Sequence numbers as the PK instead of setting the column as Identity? The DBAs want me to use sequence numbers so that the IDs stay contiguous and don't skip by 1000 every time the server instance is restarted.

Every workaround I've seen seems to be a bit fragile.

Comment: What, exactly, is the problem that needs working around? Doesn't marking the column `identity` in your model make EF treat the column "correctly", regardless of whether this is actually implemented in the database as a trigger and a sequence rather than an actual identity? Or is your question about how to produce such a database with code first?

Comment: You will kill performance if you try to get MAX+1. Take a look to: [How do I create a table with a column that uses a sequence?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53261/how-do-i-create-a-table-with-a-column-that-uses-a-sequence)

Comment: We use  code first on existing tables to build our data access layers.